# GUI for Database

Tags: oracle

I need to create a Database using Oracle. after that I have to create a GUI(Graphical User Interface) to manipulate some instructions like displaying Results, to plot some Curves, or Edit some Fields.
Which Software can you please recommend me to use?

Comment: I'm afraid that this is what's called a "shopping-list" question and will be closed! Take a look at the "Questions" section [`here`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/34007/v%C3%A9race?tab=profile) (disclaimer - my profile), especially the bits about the Tour and the Help Centre. p.s. welcome to the forum! p.p.s. recommend Oracle JDeveloper for simply getting data. As for plotting curves &c. - take your pick. Anything from Excel to Python, R, Tableau... list is endless and my/your opinion is as good as anyone else's - which is why such questions are considered off-topic :-)

Answer (score 1):

Oracle Application Express (APEX} is a web based Rapid Application Development (tool) that allows you to create web based application very easily.  It is licensed with the database.  But, it only works with Oracle databases.

Beyond rhat, it depends on your knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for answering, this would be my first experience dealing with  Databases. I started to learn SQL and Databases Basics and that was ok. And when I am done with the creation of the Database, I would have to create a graphical User interface to Edit, compare and manage some other instructions.